# How to programmatically specify video stream rotation when using Facebook Live Video API

Tags: android, facebook, live-streaming

We've implemented streaming live video from an Android app using Facebook Live Video API, and the resulting feed (as seen on Facebook) is rotated by 90 degrees.

My source video stream is indeed rotated, and usually a "rotation" property can be passed so that the video player knows to correct for this. I can't correct my source stream since it arrives from an external hardware camera that has to be mounted sideways. I've searched Facebook's documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/live-video-api), but couldn't find any way to provide the rotation.

Btw, other streaming solutions do support setting a rotation, for example see YouTube's fileDetails.videoStreams[].rotation property (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)

Comment: I can’t find anything in the docs regarding orientation, so they might simply not offer this as an option. But then, external hardware that can’t be mounted the correct way up is not really Facebook’s problem to begin with, I’d say. So you might have to find a way to embed an additional component on your end, that “corrects” the video stream before you pass it on to the API.

Comment: _“other streaming solutions do support setting a rotation, for example see YouTube's […]”_ - that’s apples and oranges, YouTube is not a _live_ streaming platform, they have plenty of time to process the user’s uploaded video because it does not happen in real time.

Comment: @04FS, thanks for the quick comments. Regarding your first point - in my case it's external hardware, but in many cases cameras on Android devices generate video that needs to be rotated (e.g., portrait vs. landscape). Regarding the second point - YouTube also supports Live Streaming. However, I'll double-check if the rotation property applies there or only to non-live videos.